# Propagating of shock waves in an ideal gas

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, shock-waves

I am studying gas dynamics and I want to numerically calculate the propagation of a shock wave in an ideal gas.
The problem statement is something like this:

The ideal gas is located in the region $-\infty<x<\infty$. We will give kinetic energy to some area for example: $0<x<1$. So, we have a boundary with a break in the normal component of the velocity.

I would like to know how to compose an equations for this problem in order to solve it numerically later.

P.s. Also, I'd like to read something about this theme.

Comment: What's your proficiency in Math, Physics, and numerical methods? If you're attending some university course, I'd suggest you to have a look at the Leveque's *Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws*. 
When you give me the info I asked, I could give you an answer, or even start a Colab

Answer (score 2):

You would be interested in the [Eulerian hydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)) equations, which are a simplification of the [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) under the assumption of zero viscosity. In [conservation form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)#Conservation_form_3), this would be expressed as,
\begin{align}
  \partial_t\rho+\nabla\cdot(\rho\mathbf{u}) &= 0 \\
  \partial_t(\rho\mathbf u)+\nabla\cdot(\rho\mathbf{uu}+p\mathbf{I}) &= 0 \\
  \partial_tE+\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{u}\left(E+p\right)) &=0
\end{align}
where $\rho$ is the density, $\mathbf{u}$ the velocity, $p$ the pressure, $\mathbf{I}$ the identity matrix and $E$ the total energy. The pressure and total energy are related via the closure condition,
$$E=\frac{p}{\gamma-1}+\frac{1}{2}\rho u^2$$

In order to solve this system of equations, you need to use a discrete derivative like [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Finite_difference), [finite volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method) or [finite element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) method. Due to the discontinuity/shock you'd develop, FEM might be one option to avoid as it isn't nearly as easy to work with as compared to FDM/FVM when such a case arises.

In one dimension, we let a generic variable transform from continuous to discrete via
$$\phi(x,\,t)\to\phi(x_i,\,t^n)\equiv\phi_i^n.$$
And then we would use these in our PDEs to obtain a discrete PDE; for instance, the conservation of mass would take the form,
$$\frac{\rho_i^{n+1}-\rho_i^n}{t^{n+1}-t^n}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\rho_{i+1}^nu_{i+1}^n-\rho_{i-1}^nu_{i-1}^n}{x_{i+1}-x_{i-1}}=0$$
where I'm assuming a central difference scheme in space and a forward difference in time (my experience is this way, at least; you could go other ways with other complications to deal with).

After writing out the full set of discrete PDEs, you would be able to plug it into any programming language that supports vectors/arrays/lists (while languages like Python might be good for quick development, it'll necessarily be slower than using a compiled language like C/C++, Rust or Fortran).

---

If you are interested in developing a fluid solver, probably the best book you could peruse for help would be Randy LeVeque's [*Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems*](https://amath.washington.edu/research/publications/finite-volume-methods-hyperbolic-problems), which covers all of the math and numerical aspects of such problems using the finite volume method (which helps smooth out jumps in the domain that finite difference method cannot handle well).

Comment: central difference is very likely to blow up with shocks. I'd go with an upwind scheme at first to check it the software works, and then implement a higher-order scheme

Comment: Finite difference in general will blow up with shocks. Better to go finite volume and smooth out the changes with a [TVD flux limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_limiter) like minmod, MC or superbee.